# Linear interpolation along a "Bresenham line"

Tags: algorithm, graphics, graphics2d

I'm using linear interpolation for animating an object between two 2d coordinates on the screen. This is pretty close to what I want, but because of rounding, I get a jagged motion. In ASCII art:

```
ooo
  ooo
    ooo
      oo
```

Notice how it walks in a Manhattan grid, instead of taking 45 degree turns. What I'd like is linear interpolation along the line which [Bresenham's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) would have created:

```
oo
  oo
    oo
      oo
```

For each x there is only one corresponding y. (And swap x/y for a line that is steep)

So why don't I just use Bresenham's algorithm? I certainly could, but that algorithm is iterative, and I'd like to know just one coordinate along the line.

I am going to try solving this by linearly interpolating the x coordinate, round it to the pixel grid, and then finding the corresponding y. (Again, swap x/y for steep lines). No matter how that solution pans out, though, I'd be interested in other suggestion and maybe previous experience.

Comment: I'd say that your rounding idea sounds like the way to go.

Comment: I'm not sure a different sort of rounding would fix that. Do you really have to round the coordinates to the pixel grid? What do you use for rendering?

Comment: @Qnan: Yes, in this case I need to round to the pixel grid, since I'm pasting images. Pixel perfect is the only thing that would look good.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bresenham's algorithm for lines was introduced to draw a complete line a bit faster than usual approaches. It has two major advantages:

- It works on integer variables
- It works iteratively, which is fast, when drawing the complete line

The first advantage is not a great deal, if you calculate only some coordinates. The second advantage turns out as a disadvantage when calculating only some coordinates. So after all, there is no need to use Bresenham's algorithm.

Instead, you can use a different algorithm, which results in the same line. For example the DDA (digital differential analyzer). This is basically, the same approach you mentioned.

First step: Calculate the slope.

```
m = (y_end - y_start) / (x_end - x_start)
```

Second step: Calculate the iteration step, which is simply:

```
i = x - x_start
```

Third step: Calculate the coresponding y-value:

```
y = y_start + i * m
  = y_start + (x - x_start) * (y_end - y_start) / (x_end - x_start)
```

Comment: You may want to take into account that rounding of 0.5 goes to 1, which is in principle unfair. The result is a line that is not symmetrical. In some cases you cannot avoid it (for instance when connecting corner points in a grid 2x3), but in other cases you could (for example in a grid 5x3). Even a standard windows paint program makes this mistake. A solution could be to switch the rounding direction of 0.5 in the middle of the line.

Comment: `.5` will occur if the line passes through the middle of two neighboring pixels. You cannot uniquely decide for one of them (i.e. one is not more correct than the other). Rounding up is just a convention, not a mistake.

Comment: No, that is fine in some cases, but in other cases this leads into asymmetric line, which looks ugly, and simply by using the above method, you can get a more suitable and more pretty rendering of a line. After all it is a computer graphics, so yes, you can be proud on your conventions...and look...ugly.

Comment: Ah, now I got what you mean. Yes, that's a valid approach.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution I ended up with:

```
public static Vector2 BresenhamLerp(Vector2 a, Vector2 b, float percent)
{
    if (a.x == b.x || Math.Abs(a.x - b.x) < Math.Abs(a.y - b.y))
    {
        // Didn't do this part yet. Basically, we just need to recurse
        // with x/y swapped and swap result on return
    }

    Vector2 result;
    result.x = Math.Round((1-percent) * a.x + percent * b.x);

    float adjustedPercent = (result.x - a.x + 0.5f) / (b.x - a.x);
    result.y = Math.Round((1-adjustedPercent) * a.y + adjustedPercent * b.y);

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I just figured out would work. Probably not the most beautiful interpolations, but it is just a 1-2 float additions per iteration on the line with a one-time precalculation. Works by calculating the number of steps on a manhattan matrix.

Ah, and it does not yet catch the case when the line is vertical (dx = 0)

This is the *naive* bresenham, but the iterations could in theory only use integers as well. If you want to get rid of the float color value, things are going to get harder because the line might be longer than the color difference, so delta-color < 1.

```
void Brepolate( uint8_t* pColorBuffer, uint8_t cs, float xs, float ys, float zs, uint8_t ce, float xe, float ye, float ze )
{
    float nColSteps = (xe - xs) + (ye - ys);
    float fColInc = ((float)cs - (float)ce) / nColSteps;
    float fCol = cs;

    float dx = xe - xs;
    float dy = ye - ys;

    float fCol = cs;

    if (dx > 0.5)
    {
        float de = fabs( dy / dx );
        float re = de - 0.5f;

        uint32_t iY = ys;
        uint32_t iX;

        for (   uint32_t    iX = xs;
                            iX <= xe;
                            iX++ )
        {
            uint32_t off = surf.Offset( iX, iY );
            pColorBuffer[off] = fCol;
            re += de;
            if (re >= 0.5f)
            {
                iY++;
                re -= 1.0f;
                fCol += fColInc;
            }
            fCol += fColInc;
        }
    }
}
```